# Size of the new Starship Launch tower at Boca Chica?

Tags: spacex-starship, launchpad, spacex-super-heavy

What is the size of the new Starship Launch tower at Boca Chica?

[RGV Aerial](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQbKe0RZ62u47TZ8vmKNnRA) estimates the size of the new Starship Launch tower at [55-60 feet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEJ4a.png). I don't think that's accurate.

Is there a better estimate of the size?

[image]

Comment: Why on earth is there an opinion-based close vote?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The pier is just shy of 3 pickups in width as you can see in the photo below from [RGV Aerial](https://youtu.be/iYEDVMcsDKA?t=31).

The overall length of a Chevrolet Silverado pickup truck 4x2 double cab with 6.6-foot box is [231.8 inches](https://media.chevrolet.com/media/us/en/chevrolet/vehicles/silverado/2020.tab1.html). Three pickups end-to-end will total 58 ft.

So the width of the base of the tower is slightly less, about 56 ft or 17 meters. That would be the length of the short diagonal of the hexagon.

[image: Image of Starship launch tower]

RGV's estimate is not too large. It's right on the money. Thanks to Xcali for pointing out my error.

Comment: I believe that length you looked up is the wheelbase rather than the overall length.  End-to-end, the truck is over 200 inches in its smallest version.